# mq_receive throws error saying message too long

Tags: c, posix, message-queue

I am new to linux programming trying to acheive a simple msg queue working .
But get the error saying message to long , below is my code please suggest if any corrections.

i know similar question is asked many times but i couldnt find solution to my probelm hence posting the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>           
#include <sys/stat.h>        
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

void* producerThRoutine (void *arg);
void* ConsumerThRoutine (void *arg);

int main()
{
  int retVal = 0;
  pthread_t producerThId,consumerThID;
  mqd_t myMQdes;
  struct mq_attr attr;  

  attr.mq_flags = 0;  
  attr.mq_maxmsg = 1024;  
  attr.mq_msgsize = 10;  
  attr.mq_curmsgs = 0; 

  myMQdes = mq_open("/myMessageQueue",O_CREAT | O_RDWR,S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR,&attr);
  if(myMQdes == (mqd_t) -1){
    perror("Message Queue creation failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  retVal = pthread_create(&producerThId,NULL,producerThRoutine,&myMQdes);
  if(retVal != 0){
    perror("\n producerThRoutine creation failed \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
  }

  retVal = pthread_create(&consumerThID,NULL,ConsumerThRoutine,&myMQdes);
  if(retVal != 0){
    perror("\n ConsumerThRoutine creation failed \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
  }

  retVal = pthread_join(producerThId,NULL);
  if(retVal != 0){
    perror("\n pthread_join for producer thread failed \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
  }

  retVal = pthread_join(consumerThID,NULL);
  if(retVal != 0){
    perror("\n pthread_join for consumer thread failed \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
  }
  mq_close(myMQdes);
  mq_unlink("/myMessageQueue");
  return 0; 
}


void* producerThRoutine (void *arg)
{
  char c;   
  char EOS = '\0';
  int retVal;
  mqd_t *pMQDes = (mqd_t *) arg;
  printf("Enter the string you want to convert to upper case \n");

  while( (c=getchar()) != EOF ){
    if(c == '\n'){
        retVal = mq_send( (*pMQDes),&EOS,sizeof(char),1);
        if(retVal != 0){
            perror("sending EOS to queue failed \n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);         
        }
        break;
    }       
    retVal = mq_send( (*pMQDes),&EOS,sizeof(char),1);
    if(retVal != 0){
        perror("sending character to queue failed \n");
        break ;         
    }
  }
}

 void* ConsumerThRoutine (void *arg)
 {
   char msg;
   int msg_priority,retVal;

   mqd_t *pMQDes = (mqd_t *) arg;

   while(1){
    printf("\nthe converted string is : ");
```

> retVal = mq_receive (*pMQDes,&msg,sizeof(char),&msg_priority);

```
    if(retVal == -1){
        perror("mq_receive failed");    
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }
    if( msg == '\0')
    {
        break;
    }
    putchar(toupper(msg));
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please indicate the code line which gives you that error, and copy paste the error message so we can see it too.

Comment: the error line is higlited

Answer (score 1):

I have just checked the man page of mq_receive, and one of the error is shown as follow:

```
EMSGSIZE
          msg_len was less than the mq_msgsize attribute of the message queue.
```

and I change the

```
retVal = mq_receive (*pMQDes,&msg,sizeof(char),&msg_priority);
```

to

```
retVal = mq_receive (*pMQDes,&msg,1024 * sizeof(char),&msg_priority);
```

where the 1024 is the mq_msgsize you set. Then the error disappear.

Comment: Note that you then really should pass in an array that have 1024 elements, right now `msg` is just a single char.

Comment: Sorry, the `mq_msgsize` is 10,  the value is best set to 10.